# Java manually boxing vs autoboxing of primitive numbers

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I was working in some code recently, and when reviewed by a colleague, was told that I made a mistake by removing the manual boxing of double values. I hadn't thought about it, but I only did so because IntelliJ recommended that I change it, so I did.

I was pointed to page 221 of Effective Java (2nd Edition) by this colleague, which talks about how Boxed primitives can be null, and relying on autounboxing can cause potential null pointer exceptions (among other things)... but in this case, I was removing manual boxing and letting the compiler deal with it.

Why should it matter, though? If I have a method that requires a `Double`, as a parameter, and was previously passing in `new Double(5.0)`, but change it to `5` instead, what are the potential implications?

Comment: It shouldn't change anything. The compiler will replace a `Double` parameter with value `5` with `Double.valueOf(5)`. A `Double` *can* be null, but if you're passing a `double`, it won't be.

Comment: Is there a reason why IntelliJ would recommend to remove manual boxing?

Comment: Is there an overloaded method or constructor that can have a different behaviour?

Comment: It makes code unnecessarily verbose.

Comment: IntelliJ in this case probably wants to just remove boiler plate code. It is also a kind of update of pre-boxing java, and `Double.valueOf` would also have been better style.

Comment: What you did was right.  Assuming there are no issues with different versions of the method overriding each other (for example, one where a parameter is an Object and another where the same parameter is a double; in which case it can cause confusion over which one will get called); then it's better not to be so verbose.  My opinion is that your colleague was wrong to flag this.  It's certainly not a mistake - if it were, IntelliJ would not have recommended it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I have a method that requires a Double, as a parameter, and was previously passing in new Double(5.0), but change it to 5 instead, what are the potential implications?

There are no bad implications, because this is *boxing*, not *unboxing*. As such, you wouldn't get an NPE here, nor would you if you unboxed it in the method to which you pass the value.

In fact, passing `5` as a `Double` parameter isn't quite the same as passing `new Double(5.0)` - it is actually `Double.valueOf(5.0)`. And the advantage of that is in the Javadoc:

> Returns a Double instance representing the specified double value. If a new Double instance is not required, this method should generally be used in preference to the constructor Double(double), as this method is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance by caching frequently requested values.

So, you get better performance by passing `Double.valueOf(5.0)`, because of caching; but you can just use the far less-verbose `5` instead.

---

However, you have to be slightly careful, if you have overloads: some of these methods might have a more-specific method signature than the one taking the `Double`, and so would be called in preference.

Answer (score 4):

The boxing example you gave is totally fine.
The problem is the unboxing. You will have NPE if you try to get primitive from null object wrapper:

```
Double d = null;

double d1 = d; // here you will get NPE
```